# Please check my proof that $\inf(bS) = b\sup(S)$ when $b<0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I'm asked the following:

Prove that if b<0, then inf(bS)=bsup(S).

My attempt was as follows:

Proof:

Let b<0 and sup(S)=X

This gives that X$\leq$s for s$\epsilon$S.

This gives that bX is the greatest lower bound for bS. *****

Therefore bX=inf(bS) (1)

Now

Let b<0 and inf(bS)=Y

For all z$\epsilon$S, we have Y$\leq$bz, equivalent to (y/b)$\leq$z

This gives that y/b is an upper bound for S.

For all z$\epsilon$S, Y/b=sup(S)

This gives y=bsup(S) (2)

Combining (1) and (2) completes the proof.

QED

&&&&&

I turned this in a little while ago and received it back having only received half credit. Professor says I should know my mistake but I can't identify what it is. He marked the lines around the *****.

Please provide corrections to my proof.

Additionally, no mater the question I ask, I get downvoted and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong when I ask my questions. Advise to prevent this is also appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Two pointers for not getting down-voted: 1. Format your questions with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I notice others have previously linked you to this tutorial, and that you did this with the matrices in your previous question, which is a good start, but you should be doing this with all your mathematics. Also, 2. you need a more informative title. I suggest, `Please check my proof that $\inf(bS) = b\sup(S)$ when $b<0$`.

Comment: Well, when $\sup S=X$ then it means that $X\geq s$ for all $s\in S$. You have written the inequality in reverse. And further (assuming the inequality was a typo) one can't infer at this point that $bX$ is the glb of $bS$ just by that inequality.

Comment: What is $S$? What is $b$? It is on the person writing to be clear on the question [this includes using proper formatting w MathJax], and this question is poorly written.

Comment: Please go through the [mathjax tutorial especially designed for beginners](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/72031) and typeset your question using mathjax wherever necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure why your professor didn't write lines where you say, "this gives that $X \leq s$ for all $s \in S$." If that were true then $X$ would be the infimum of $S$ and not the supremum. And $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, right?